# STM32L4 LPTIM as pulse counter of intermittent pulses fails when initializing with no pulse

Tags: stm32, timer, low-power

I'm working with LPTIM as a Pulse Counter on a STM32L432KC, I have a rain gauge connected to LPTIM1 (PB5) and a anemometer to LPTIM2 (PB1). Both configured on STM32CubeMX as Standalone: counts external clock events and pins assigned as LPTIM?_IN1 using LSE clock.

To simplify, let's just use the anemometer but the symptoms is happening on the rain gauge as well.

Initializing the counter:

```
HAL_LPTIM_Counter_Start(&hlptim2, 0xffff);
```

This returns HAL_TIMEOUT when there's no pulse (no wind). If I turn the anemometer with my hand or is winding, when the device is initializing, it returns HAL_OK and it works just fine after that.

Troubleshooting, I found where it's timing out. On stm32l4xx_hal_lptim.c, HAL_LPTIM_Counter_Start function, you can find this code:

```
  /* Load the period value in the autoreload register */
  __HAL_LPTIM_AUTORELOAD_SET(hlptim, Period);

  /* Wait for the completion of the write operation to the LPTIM_ARR register */
  if (LPTIM_WaitForFlag(hlptim, LPTIM_FLAG_ARROK) == HAL_TIMEOUT)
  {
    return HAL_TIMEOUT;
  }
```

There's [application note AN4865](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00290631-lowpower-timer-lptim-applicative-use-cases-on-stm32-microcontrollers-stmicroelectronics.pdf) related to use LPTIM as a pulse counter and it doesn't say anything about LPTIM_ARR register neither LPTIM_ISR waiting for ARROK flag (4th bit). Also, on the example code, they expect a constant pulse signal arriving so this problem never happens.

If I comment `if (LPTIM_WaitForFlag...` block, it works perfectly.

I'm not sure if this is a bug or not, and if is, how to report to STMicroelectronics.

Comment: Do you call HAL_LPTIM_MspInit() before starting the counter? It seems on the ST forums that someone is having this exact problem and exact "fix" too. Anyway, something is holding the micro back from raising that specific flag. Are your clock configured correctly?

Comment: HAL_LPTIM_MspInit() is being called, and the timers are correct I guess. It’s using LSE, other peripherals like LPUART are also being driven by LSE and working fine. I tried to upload the AN4865 code as is, and the same symptoms happens.

Comment: I opened this [github issue #24](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeL4/issues/24)

Comment: Cool, I'm curious what the problem is. I'm involuntary experienced with strange HAL bugs..

Comment: I had the same problem, my problem root is found on msp.c and lptim msp init.